# Alternative for Challenge as section header

Tags: word-choice, heading

All,

I am preparing a technical document for a process. Another team will do the implementation based on the document.

I want to have a section which will outline some of the challenges they will face and how to overcome them. I am currently leaning towards "Challenges", but are there any better alternatives?

For the context, some other headers are 1. Requirement, 2. Analysis, 3. Technical Solution, 4. Dependencies etc.

Update: I was thinking of another heading as I will be telling about how to overcome the challenges also in this section - like "Challenges and how to overcome them"

Comment: *Challenges* sounds a bit 'flip' in the context of the other section names. Besides, how do *you* know which particular aspects of the implementation the team will find challenging? If they're any good they'll find out for themselves, and it should be no part of your spec to tell them where their strengths and weaknesses lie. Just say what the process has to do.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - We are trying to make life easier for all. I know what challenges they will face and how to overcome them because I have done a similar implementation before. So I would not want the implementation team spend time reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Perhaps it should be *Guidance notes* then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use "Special Considerations" for our similar section header.  It allows everyone to save face, and it allows us to detail some of the finer points that other sections may miss.

Answer (score 1):

If this section contains "gotcha" warnings not covered elsewhere, I think "Challenges" is a fine heading (or "Implementation Challenges" if that level of specificity applies to your situation).  If this section calls out information that is covered elsewhere, e.g. you talk about requirements-based challenges in Requirements and design/implementation challenges in Technical Solution and so on, then perhaps "Summary of Challenges" would be better.

Answer (score 0):

"Challenges" is certainly a viable option, and fits your short description very nicely.  "Issues" would also do, and has essentially the same connotations in these circumstances.